# Supporting multiple social sign-in methods

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, oauth

I have performed a number of searches on this topic and found some related questions however none of which provided a clear picture of the best practice for developing a sign-in system on a site that relys on 3rd party server-side OAuth.

We have opted not to offer a traditional member sign-in method, allowing users to log in to the site via Facebook or Twitter (we may choose to offer further support for other networks at a later date).

We are keen to provide a seemless user experience for both new and returning users and would appreciate some advice & best practice from anyone who has successfully done this in the past.

**The initial plan was as follows**
- When a user signs in via Facebook we require them to provide a username which will be used throughout the site
- When a user signed in via Twitter we use their Twitter name as our username

This approach has an obvious flaw. What if a Twitter user signs in only to find that their username is being used by another member who chose it via signing in with Facebook?

This is unacceptable user experience therefore we need to re-think.

**New approach**
Currently our new approach is upon initial sign-in to present the user with a form to provide the remaining required information

For Twitter sign-ins:
 - Display name. Pre-populated with Twitter username if available or suffixed with 0,1,2,3 etc..
 - Email address. This will be confirmed via a verification email to complete the sign-up process.

For Facebook sign-ins:
 - Display name. Pre-populated with Facebook Display name if supplied & available or suffixed with 0,1,2,3 etc..
 - Email address. Pre-populated from Facebook account, no need to verify unless they decide to use a different email address, in which can the process will be the same as above.

It would be great to hear your thoughts on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think second style is the simple one  and user can feel  less burden .
my vote for second only .He can pushed to login in the that same page and felt free.

hey ! just post weather which style you decided at the end ..because  I need to know the result of this $100 question :))